# Have a problem with inputAddress lightning component(Google autocomplete)

Tags: lightning

In my `inputAddress` lightning component, I have attribute `showAddressLookup=true`. But it doesnt work and I don't have "Google autocomplete" feature there, below is the code

```
    <lightning:inputAddress addressLabel="Address" streetLabel="Street" cityLabel="City" countryLabel="Country" provinceLabel="Province" postalCodeLabel="PostalCode" street="" city="{! v.attr}" country="US" province="" postalCode="" required="false" showAddressLookup="true" />
```

Comment: Hi @Ahtoh please add more information so that we can help you. You can add component code here

Comment: its look like
<lightning:inputAddress
                addressLabel="Address"
                streetLabel="Street"
                cityLabel="City"
                countryLabel="Country"
                provinceLabel="Province"
                postalCodeLabel="PostalCode"
                street=""
                city="{! v.attr}"
                country="US"
                province=""
                postalCode=""
                required="false"
                showAddressLookup="true"
        />

Answer (score 0):

According the the `lightning:inputAddress` [component documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputAddress/documentation), the Google Places API autocomplete feature is only available under certain circumstances (likely due to API licensing and usage concerns).

> Using showAddressLookup is not supported in Communities, standalone apps, Lightning Out, and Lightning Components for Visualforce.

If you're using the component in any of those cases the autocomplete feature is not available.